# C++ breakpoints not hit when debugging a mixed Python/C++ project

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

I am currently debugging a Python application that integrates C++ functionalities using `pybind11`.

I'm troubleshooting under a Linux Docker environment.

I have set up the debugger with the following `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "myscript.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "/usr/local/bin/python",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my `setup.py`:

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension

os.environ["CPPFLAGS"] = "-g"

setup(name="my_add",
      version="1.0.0",
      ext_modules=[Pybind11Extension("my_add", ["add.cpp"]],
      )
```

The debugger works fine and I can switch between cpp and python files. However, I encountered an issue where breakpoints set in `add.cpp` were not being hit. As illustrated in the provided screenshot, the debugger appears to skip directly over these breakpoints without halting execution:

[image]

Comment: Does disabling optimizations help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler optimized the cpp files. To solve the problem, I added the `-O0` flag which tells gcc/g++ to not optimize the code. So I modified the `setup.py` as follows:

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension

os.environ["CPPFLAGS"] = "-O0 -g"

setup(name="my_add",
      version="1.0.0",
      ext_modules=[Pybind11Extension("my_add", ["add.cpp"]],
      )
```